# why does this hashtag regex extraction leave this in the front? "--- -"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Here's the regex that I'm using for hashtag extraction

```
def extract_hashtags
       hashtag_regex = /\B#(\w+)/i
       text_hashtags = content.scan(hashtag_regex)
       text_hashtags.each do |tag|
         hashtags.create hashtags: tag
       end
     end
```

Using `/\B#(\w+)/i`, leaves this in the front of the data

For example, the extraction should be "abcd", but it is saved as "--- - abcd"

What should the regex be change to in order to extract just the #abcd?

If the post content (where the hashtag is extracted) is something like "Hello stackoverflow #stackoverflow", it gets saved into the database as "-- - stackoverflow"

Comment: I tried without \B and tried to extract "#checkme" from a post, but I got "--- - checkme"

Comment: `>> "Hello stackoverflow #stackoverflow".scan(/\B#(\w+)/i)
=> [["stackoverflow"]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test = "Hello stackoverflow #stackoverflow"
test.scan( /\B#(\w+)/i )
 => [["stackoverflow"]]
```

I suspect you are storing the array `["stackoverflow"]`, and from the resulting string, is your storage using YAML to handle structured data?

I think you just want to alter the create line:

```
text_hashtags.each do |tag|
  hashtags.create hashtags: tag[0]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The `"--- -"` is prepended by the database layer of Rails when converting the array to YAML. `"---"` is the YAML prefix, and `"-"` indicates the first element of the array.

When you read it back from the database, Rails will do the inverse transformation: it will rebuild the original array, and remove the dashes.